# Can I use Azure AD B2C as a login for OneDrive?

Tags: azure, onedrive, azure-ad-b2c, azure-files

Is it possible to use Azure AD B2C to create and login to OneDrive? What I want to do is write a mobile app that uses the Azure AD B2C database to allow a user to login then create a OneDrive instance for them and use it to save and load files.

I'm sure this is possible to do with Azure's File Storage but I don't want to have to implement all the file storage UI functionality in my app. OneDrive already implements this for me.

Answer (score 2):

It should be supported, however it's advised to use Microsoft Graph instead. This is the old process for authenticating to OneDrive through AAD [**here:**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/aad-oauth)

*Getting an application configured for access to OneDrive for Business is a challenge. We're working on making this process easier, so please bear with us.
In this section, you'll learn how to:
Register your app with Azure Active Directory.
Sign into OneDrive for Business
The OneDrive API uses the standard OAuth 2.0 authentication scheme to authenticate users and generate access tokens. You provide an access token for every API call via an HTTP header.*

The new process which is based on using **MS Graph** is similar in some steps, it is documented [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth)